# Using October CMS for specific pages

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-partial

I want to use Octobercms for my laravel project. The main question is that can I use Octobercms for specific parts of my website?
I mean for example single blog pages

Comment: hmm seems you have already laravel project running and for blog pages you want to use october cms right ?

Comment: Yes it is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use **sub-domain method.**

> Many organisations are using this method

https://mainstite.com <- pointing to main site

https://blog.mainsite.com <- pointing to blog **[** `Just redirect user to blog sub-domain from main site` **]**

This will give you more advantage and flexibility you can use `2 separate folders`

- 1 for your main site
- 2 and another for your blog

As well you can have `single db` or `multiple db dedicated to blog only [october cms only]` (so maintaining blog can be easy with dedicated blog db)

As **from your main site** you can access `blog data from blog database` also you can `insert update and delete blogs` as `laravel` can access multiple db at once.

You can share session between `sub domains` as well **[ plus point ]**.

If you have any further question please comment.

Answer (score 0):

This discussion may be of use to you

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/integrate-a-cms-into-laravel-5

There's a number of solutions presented in this thread. Hopefully something in here is helpful for you!